# rectangles on a grid

Tags: c++, grid

Here is code for a square, 25 x 25 grid made of dots.  I need to get input from the user, x1, x2, y1, y2, and two characters such as @ and /, and have this create a rectangle with one character filling the interior and one outlining the rectangle.  I'm not sure how to work these inputs into the loop and create said rectangle.
This is the header file....

```
// Rectangle.h

#ifndef Rectangle_h
#define Rectangle_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
private:
float length, width, perimeter, area;
int a, i, j, h, x1, x2, y1, y2;
char inner;

public:
Rectangle();    // default constructor

void printGrid();
void setValues();
void setIntChar();


};

#endif
```

This is the source code....

```
void Rectangle::setValues()
{
do
{
    cout << "Enter x1, x2, y1, and y2 such that x1 < x2 and y1 < y2:\n";
    cin >> x1;
    cin >> x2;
    cin >> y1;
    cin >> y2;
}
while(x1 >= x2 || y1 >= y2);

cout << endl << "Rectangle accepted.\n\n";
}

void Rectangle::setIntChar()
{
cout << "Enter a character to fill the interior of the rectangle: \n" << endl;
cin >> inner;
cout << endl << endl;
}

void Rectangle::printGrid()
{
for(i = 0; i < 25; i++) // prints 25 rows of 25 dots and a space after each dot
{   
    if(i < 16)
    cout << 25 - i << " ";// prints 25 - 10 in descending order 

if(i > 15)
    cout << 25 - i << "  "; // prints 9 - 1 in descending order

for(j = 0; j < 25; j++) // prints a line of 25 dots and 2 spaces after each dot
    cout << ".  ";

for(h = 0; h < 25; h++) // prints a line of 25 double-spaces
    cout << "  ";

cout << endl;       // ends the line after each iteration       
}

cout << "   ";

for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
{
    if(i < 10)
        cout << i << "  ";

    if(i > 9)
    cout << i << " ";
}

cout << endl << endl;
```

}

This is the main function....

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

///// main /////

int main()
{
Rectangle grid; // creates an object of the Rectangle class

grid.setValues();
grid.setIntChar();
grid.printGrid();
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is a class assignment, the will probably deduct points for you using magic numbers like "25" throughout the code.  You've probably learned about constants already.  Maybe not.

For inputs, they told you about cin and cout, yes?  Don't worry about a loop.  Just get them and use them to call your function.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your advice.  The rectangle needs to appear in the grid.  "Just get them and use them to call your function".  Can you clarify this a little for me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know how far along in the C++ you've learned, but it appears you're using classes?  What all are the member variables of the Rectangle class?  Presumably it's something like

```
class Rectangle {
    public:
        Rectangle();  // constructor sets member variables to default values
        void getInputFromUser();  // using stdout and stdin, prompts the user for x1, y1, x2, y2, line char, fill char, and sets the member variables to these values
        void printGrid(); // uses member variables to determine how to print the grid

        ...

    private:
        // private methods

        ...

        // private variables

        int m_x1;
        int m_x2;
        int m_y1;
        int m_y2;
        char m_lineChar;
        char m_fillChar;

        // static constants

        static const int kMinXValue; // set to 0 in the cpp file
        static const int kMinYValue; // set to 0 in the cpp file
        static const int kMaxXValue; // set to 25 in the cpp file
        static const int kMaxYValue; // set to 25 in the cpp file
};
```

So, in your class, your implementation of getInputFromUser() is going to have some lines of code like `cout << "Please enter the top left corner's x value << endl;` and `cin >> m_x1;`.

Your implementation of printGrid() is going to have some lines of code like `for(int y = kMinYValue; y < kMaxYValue; y++) { // iterate through the rows` and `if( y == m_y1 || y == m_y2) { // we need to print the m_lineChar value if the x value is in range`

Hopefully that answers your question enough for you to solve the problem.  If you need specific help with specific problems, you're going to need to be more specific with what you've done, what your code is, and what your problem with the code you have is.

Comment: I've added my header file, source  code, and main function.  This is what I'm working with.  My grid looks good, it's exactly the way I want it.  I just don't know how to take the input from the user and create a rectangle in my grid.

Comment: You already have input from the user.  I don't understand the problem?  You also need one for the outer char, so make a function like setIntChar that does it for your outer char, and a corrosponding member variable to store it.
Now in your code: `for(j = 0; j < 25; j++) // prints a line of 25 dots and 2 spaces after each dot`
I assume you want to replace the dot with the correct character?  Then this is the for loop to add the conditionals checking i and j against x1, x2, y1, and y2, to determine what to print.

Comment: Yes I want to replace the dot with the user's chosen character.  I've tried checking i and j against x1, x2, etc.  The result is the character being printed at the beginning, or the end of the line represented by the variable i.    The problem is that I can't figure out how to replace the dots with the input character to form a rectangle.

Comment: Do it in the place where you would have printed the dot.

Comment: Pseudo-code:
`if i,j is inside rectangle`
`print inside rectangle char`
`else if i,j is on edge`
`print edge char`
`else` 
`print the dot`

Comment: Right there in that for loop.  **Replacing** the code where you print the dot.

Comment: Please indicate if my comments were helpful or if my answer solved your issue, thanks!

Comment: I don't think I understand.  I take you to mean replace cout << ".  "; with cout << inner "  ";

Comment: I appreciate your help greatly.  My professor seems to think this information is intuitive.

Comment: Add "if" statements around that cout.  Sorry the comments don't format code or psuedocode well.  But you only want to do `cout << ". "` if it's outside the rectangle.  So your for loop needs if, else if, else, as mentioned in an earlier comment.  Please re-read my psuedocode.  It's hard to explain it any better in the comments here.

Comment: If it's in the rectangle, you need to do `cout << getIntChar() << " ";` **instead of** `cout << ". ";`

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense and you can "accept" my answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your comments have moved me in the right direction.  I've been able to make it do almost what I want it to do.

Comment: Awesome.  Good luck with the class!